# Amazon S3 sync Deleting excluded files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 buckets, Bucket A and Bucket B. Bucket A contains Javascript files and bucket B contains a mix of javascript and other file types. I am trying to do a sync of only JS files from bucket A to B.

I am using the following:

> aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a s3://bucket-b --delete --exclude "*"
>   --include "*.js"

I was assuming that this will leave bucket B with an exact copy of all of the js files. However the above command will start deleting all of the non js files in Bucket B.

When I run the following command:

> aws s3 sync . s3://bucket-b --delete --exclude "*"
>   --include "*.js"

With the current directory containing a copy of bucket A, bucket B will have the same js files as bucket A and non js files will not be affected.

Why is this command functioning differently when syncing local to bucket compared to bucket to bucket?

EDIT: Added CLI input/output to reproduce problem.

```
Darrrens-MBP:testFolder darren$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.7.4 Python/2.7.9 Darwin/14.4.0
Darrrens-MBP:testFolder darren$ aws s3 ls s3://tmp-test-bucket-a
2015-09-01 11:40:44          2 test1.js
2015-09-01 11:40:43          2 test2.js
Darrrens-MBP:testFolder darren$ aws s3 ls s3://tmp-test-bucket-b
2015-09-01 11:39:32          2 test1.js
2015-09-01 11:39:34          2 test2.js
2015-09-01 11:39:34          3 test3.php
Darrrens-MBP:testFolder darren$ ls
test1.js    test2.js
Darrrens-MBP:testFolder darren$ aws s3 sync . s3://tmp-test-bucket-b --delete --exclude "*" --include "*.js"
Darrrens-MBP:testFolder darren$ aws s3 sync s3://tmp-test-bucket-a s3://tmp-test-bucket-b --delete --exclude "*" --include "*.js"
delete: s3://tmp-test-bucket-b/test3.php
copy: s3://tmp-test-bucket-a/test2.js to s3://tmp-test-bucket-b/test2.js
copy: s3://tmp-test-bucket-a/test1.js to s3://tmp-test-bucket-b/test1.js
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your results. Could you show some "before & after" listings of the source & destination, together with the `sync` commands run, so we can try to reproduce the situation? Also, it's worth checking that you're using the latest version of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for getting back to me. I have updated the question to include an example of the issue. As you can see I have the same content in bucket a as in the local directory. Why is the sync result different? I am using OSX but I had the same result on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce the behaviour you experienced. No deletion from local machine, but deletion between S3 buckets. I've raised [an issue against the AWS CLI project](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1481).

Comment: thanks, I'm looking forward to see the outcome

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly,**--delete** deletes files that exist in the destination but not in the source during sync, which are the ones you exclude.better use aws s3 cp instead of aws s3 sync.

[Check AWS CLI reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)

Comment: The problem with using cp is that it will copy every file every time, with thousands of files this is not practical. We ended up changing our solution so that the sync was not necessary.